# Laravel - phpUnit test while using Doctrine

Tags: php, laravel, doctrine-orm, phpunit

I created a project with Laravel + Doctrine (instead of Eloquent) + Angular Routing  . I decided to use php unit  test for testing API (Controllers , Repositories) Actually I am geting an error while testing a simple method. Here is my code :

**DoctorineRestaurantRepositoryTest.php:**

```
    class RestaurantTest extends TestCase
     {
         private $DoctrineRepository;
         public  function setUp() {
             $this->DoctrineRepository = DoctrineRestaurantRepository::class;
           }
        /** @test */
        public function validator()
        {
            $this->DoctrineRepository->setTestVariable(3);
            $this->assertEquals($this->DoctrineRepository->getTestVariable(), 3);
        }
      .
      .
      .
    }
```

my repository file: (**DoctrineRestaurantRepository.php**)

```
class DoctrineRestaurantRepository extends DoctrineBaseRepository
{

    private $testVariable = 0;

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getTestVariable()
    {
        return $this->testVariable;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $testVariable
     */
    public function setTestVariable($testVariable)
    {
        $this->testVariable = $testVariable;
    }

  .
  .
  .
}
```

I ran test and it gave an error :

```
Call to a member function setTestVariable() on string
```

Any suggestion to fix it?

Comment: Did you injected DoctrineRepository in __construct ? i think you need to check whether its being injected or not.

Comment: Where is $this->DoctrineRepository created? Sounds like your referencing the class name like DoctrineRepository::class.

Comment: @btl I've edited my question.

Comment: You're not instantiating DoctrineRestaurantRepository... you need to call new DoctrineRestaurantRepository() or bind it to the app service container for later resolving. $this->app->bind(DoctrineRestaurantRepository::class, new DoctrineRestaurantRepository()); then you can use it later with $this->app->make(DoctrineRestaurantRepository::class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the class variable or inject the class in the method.

> Solution 1
>
> adding new object to the class variable

```
use DoctrineRestaurantRepository;

class RestaurantTest extends TestCase
{
    private $DoctrineRepository;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->DoctrineRepository = new DoctrineRestaurantRepository;
    }
    /** @test */
    public function validator()
    {
        $this->DoctrineRepository->setTestVariable(3);
        $this->assertEquals($this->DoctrineRepository->getTestVariable(), 3);
    }
  .
  .
  .
}
```

> Solution 2
>
> using dependency injection

```
use DoctrineRestaurantRepository;

class RestaurantTest extends TestCase
{
    private $DoctrineRepository;

    public function __construct(DoctrineRestaurantRepository $repository)
    {
        $this->DoctrineRepository = $repository;
    }
    /** @test */
    public function validator()
    {
        $this->DoctrineRepository->setTestVariable(3);
        $this->assertEquals($this->DoctrineRepository->getTestVariable(), 3);
    }
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Comment: Result of method 1 : PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to DoctrineORM\DoctrineBaseRepository::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, none given, called in DoctorineRestaurantRepositoryTest.php on line 18 and defined in /DoctrineORM/DoctrineBaseRepository.php:22

Comment: And __construct in DoctrineBaseRepository looks like this :

 public function __construct(EntityManager $em)

Comment: Then you must have to pass an instances of all dependencies when creating new instance of DoctrineRestaurantRepository